# Young-adult book - humans enslaved on a planet by aliens, people eat meat fruits

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I vaguely recall this book which was a trilogy.

Some free people are living near Jupiter or some such. People on Earth are slaves, and terraforming is taking place. On Earth, people have to cultivate plants that grow very tall and produce different tasting fruits, some that taste like meat.

Comment: What do you mean by "terraforming"? What planet is being terraformed? Do the aliens come from one of the Solar planets or moons, or are they from outside the Solar System?

Comment: When did you read this? Did it seem like a recent release then, or something older? Do you remember anything about the cover art, what sort of ethnicities were involved, how one set of people became free?

Comment: Hi I'm the same person as asked the original question- not sure why I can't log back in as the same person-
anywayz-
Earth was being terraformed, I think. I think the aliens came from outside the solar system.
I read this about 25 years ago or so- it might have been a recent release at that time. I do not recall the ethnicities. How one side became free- I do not remember that very much- I think there were robots involved, but dont recall it- I think the main character was a boy or a young man. He got out- I think by stealing a ship with some friends.

Comment: @user1063049 You can merge your accounts by following the instructions [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: [Tomeato](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0560462/)?