# Scifi book series: Humans enslaved by aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

This book was part of a trilogy. Some free humans live near Jupiter or thereabouts, the rest of the humans are on Earth where terraforming is taking place. The human slaves are fed from fruits that are grown on Earth, some of which taste like meat while others have other flavours.

That's the part that I can recall- does anyone remember this story?

Comment: Just happened to notice http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144941/young-adult-book-humans-enslaved-on-a-planet-by-aliens-people-eat-meat-fruits is very similar. Are you the same guy?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - They are the same, according to the user who posted the second one.

Comment: I guess we can't merge them as Duplicates, though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you by any chance mean the [*Atherton*](https://www.patrickcarman.com/books/atherton/) series by Patrick Carmen?

It consists of the books:

- *House of Power*
- *Rivers of Fire*
- *The Dark Planet*

> Dr. Harding is the futuristic mad scientist responsible for creating Atherton: a three tiered satellite world orbiting the fallen Earth. But those who live on Atherton don’t know Earth exists or their role in trying to save it. Edgar, a gifted climber, is the first to discover the first of many startling revelations to come: the three tiered world of Atherton is collapsing. A dangerous world of strange creatures and hidden powers with a history locked inside the mind of a mad scientist, Atherton is much more than it appears at first glance. Ages 9 and up

Comment: Your initial version of this was very brief and little more than a comment. Here we prefer answers to try and explain the why and not just the what. I've made some basic edits to add in some general information but it would be good if you could [edit] to explain how this matches. See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/58193) for details if you need too.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - That's a pretty bloody big edit you've done there

Comment: @Valorum:
Nah, basically just adding an HTML link and associated summary, pretty much just a few clicks. If he'd added excerpts from the text to match, you'd have more of a point.

Comment: That said, unless the book summaries are concerting to hide it, there's no alien slavery going on.